# Удаление функции из БД

Tags: postgresql

Имеется PostgreSQL с набором хранимых функций. Как правильно дропнуть все функции с одинаковым именем?
На данный момент используется такой код

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_s_dropfunction(functionname text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    funcrow RECORD;
    numfunctions smallint := 0;
    numparameters int;
    i int;
    paramtext text;
BEGIN
FOR funcrow IN SELECT proargtypes FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = functionname LOOP

    numparameters = array_upper(funcrow.proargtypes, 1) + 1;

    i = 0;
    paramtext = '';

    LOOP
        IF i < numparameters THEN
            IF i > 0 THEN
                paramtext = paramtext || ', ';
            END IF;
            paramtext = paramtext || (SELECT typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = funcrow.proargtypes[i]);
            i = i + 1;
        ELSE
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    EXECUTE 'DROP FUNCTION ' || functionname || '(' || paramtext || ');';
    numfunctions = numfunctions + 1;

END LOOP;

RETURN 'Dropped ' || numfunctions || ' functions';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: А что, PostgreSQL позволяет создавать функции с одинаковым именем?

Comment: Да, позволяет. Перегрузка функций как в C++, допустимы одноимённые функции с разными аргументами

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да, постгре позволяет перегрузку, в этом плюс и минус, поскольку фраза 'CREATE OR REPLACE' в случае изменения параметров функции создает новую функцию, вместо обновления старой, поэтому я сперва удаляю старую, потом создаю новую, чтобы избежать старых версий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вашу хранимку можно существенно упростить воспользовавшись штатной функцией [`pg_get_function_identity_arguments`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html). Но всё равно максимум что можно сделать - это сформировать запросы и их выполнить отдельно.

```
select 'drop function ' 
    || p.oid::regproc || '(' 
    || pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) 
    || ')' 
from pg_proc p 
where p.proname = 'dateadd';
```

В современном `psql` достаточно одного этого запроса и команды `\gexec`:

```
melkij=> select 'drop function ' || p.oid::regproc || '(' || pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) || ')' from pg_proc p where p.proname = 'dateadd';
                                 ?column?                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 drop function monitoring.dateadd()
 drop function public.dateadd(text, integer, timestamp without time zone)
 drop function public.dateadd(text, integer, timestamp with time zone)
(3 строки)

melkij=> \gexec
DROP FUNCTION
DROP FUNCTION
DROP FUNCTION
melkij=> \df dateadd
                           Список функций
 Схема | Имя | Тип данных результата | Типы данных аргументов | Тип 
-------+-----+-----------------------+------------------------+-----
(0 строк)
```

(попутно демонстрирую корректное поведение для схем)

Так же возможно использовать анонимный блок функции если для явно целей раскатки приложения не хочется плодить постоянные хранимки:

```
do $$ 
declare q text; 
begin 
    for q in select 'drop function ' || p.oid::regproc || '(' || pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) || ')' as q from pg_proc p where p.proname = 'dateadd' 
    loop 
        execute q;
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Это один запрос для клиента, доступно начиная с postgresql 9.0

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что Постгрес не имеет встроенного синтаксиса удаления всех перегруженных функций. Есть вот такая процедура (не моя), которая несколько меньше вашей:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_delfunc(_name text, OUT func_dropped int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
  _sql text;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*)::int
  , 'DROP FUNCTION ' || string_agg(oid::regprocedure::text, '; DROP FUNCTION ')
  FROM   pg_proc
  WHERE  proname = _name
  AND    pg_function_is_visible(oid)
  INTO   func_dropped, _sql;
  IF func_dropped > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE _sql;
  END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623246/1892060.